# jquery json parsing - and error

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

I have php script that returns data from DB and creates a json-style text, looking like this:

```
{ "company" : [ { "value" : "siemens" }, { "value" : "cocacola" } ], "order" : [ { "value" : "John" }, { "value" : "Mary" } ], "mob" : [ { "value" : "123123123" },  { "value" : "123123123" } ] }
```

I parse it via jquery like this:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: dir + "get_data.php", // this on gets text you can se above
        success: function(html){
            try {
                var autocomplete = $.parseJSON(html);
            }
            catch(e) {
                alert('invalid json');
                $('#content').append(html)
            }
                    }
                   })
```

Since a while it returns "invalid json" although nothing in database structure or code havent been changed. Earlier it worked all fine - just perfectly! Everything that changed are just new entries from users because data is to autocomplete fields. My first thought was that user has entered some special signs that werent filtred correctly ie quote sign or curly bracket. I checked it via http://json-validator.com/ and http://jsonlint.com/ - they both say that it is correct json. Next idea is that somehow json file is to big to be parsed and it parses part of it. Do you have any ideas what can be wrong here?

SOLUTION:

Some users entered to database tabulation sign which was messing with json parsing. If u have similiar problem - first clean DB from it and set some kind of filters to input data. Good luck. Closing!

Comment: u r right, but this one is just an example written from scratch. script returns json with no errors

Comment: so, you're saying that the 'invalid json' gets alerted and that the json passed back is correct? are you sure?

Comment: i appended json to the page and copied it to json validator - in spite of json invalid text in my page (alert) json validator says it's ok - it confusing

Comment: The JSON shown is invalid. It is missing a `{` before `"value" : "John"`

Comment: yes i know, but it's written from scratch and i misstyped it..

Comment: what does your exception say? alert html and then in catch alert `e.toString()`

Comment: Hit your PHP endpoint, watch the browser in the console and make sure its ok.

Or.. set html = the JSON string and see the response.

Comment: Is your PHP returning a `Content-type: application/json` header?  If so, then jQuery is parsing the JSON for you!  Try to `console.log(html);` before your `try{}` to see what you *really* have there.

Comment: e.message says: JSON.parse: bad control character in string literal

Comment: can i figure which line is returning an error?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you can do here:

1. Make sure you're using the latest version of jQuery.
2. Specifying a data type with jQuery's AJAX functions can help pinpoint the error. Try the following code:

   ```
   $.ajax({url: dir + "get_data.php", type: "json"})
       .done(function(data) {
           var autocomplete = data;
       })
       .fail(function(xhr, response, error) {
           alert('Request failed: ' + error);
           console.log('%o', xhr);
           $('#content').append(response);
       });
   ```

   Between the `jqXHR` object logged in the console and the `error` thrown from `$.ajax`, you might be able to get some more specific information about why parsing the JSON went wrong.
3. Finally, check [**the documentation for `jQuery.parseJSON()`**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) and make sure none of the issues with newlines and tab characters are applicable to you.